# GCP Google_Client API: How can I create Snapshot with name?

Tags: google-api, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-api-php-client

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

I'm using google-api-php-client on my google compute engine(GCE) to create a snapshot. I found that how can I get and delete snapshot but I did not find how to create it. Therefore I'm using gcloud command now like below.

```
public function backup() {

  try {
      $client = new \Google_Client();
      $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
      $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute']);

      $compute_service = new \Google_Service_Compute($client);
      try {
          $compute_service->snapshots->get('project-name', 'snapshot-name', array());
          $compute_service->snapshots->delete('project-name', 'snapshot-name', array());
      } catch (\Exception $e) {}

      exec("gcloud compute disks snapshot instance-name --snapshot-names snapshot-name --zone xxxx");

  } catch (\Exception $e) {
      Log::error($e);
  }
```

}

I found "createSnapshot" mehtod but it does not have "name" attribute and I have no idea what is "Google_Service_Compute_Snapshot" property.

```
public function createSnapshot($project, $zone, $disk, Google_Service_Compute_Snapshot $postBody, $optParams = array())
```

Could you tell me how to create snapshot by using Google_Client?

Answer (score 3):

```
$snapshot = new \Google_Service_Compute_Snapshot();
$snapshot->setName('snapshot-name');
$compute_service->disks->createSnapshot('project-name', 'asia-east1-a', 'instance-name', $snapshot, array());
```